# Paging Library Invalidate Data Source

Tags: android, datasource, invalidation, android-paging, android-paging-library

What's the simplest way to invalidate data retrieved by the paging library?
I need to do that on logout.
I've a DataSource.Factory and a DataSource that extends PageKeyedDataSource. Is it a good idea to call invalidate() on DataSource contructor? Will it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Paging library with other Architecture Components, such as `LiveData` and `LifecycleOwner` and your screen is closed on logout, the `DataSource` will be invalidated automatically.

If you don't, you still can invalidate it manually, calling

```
yourDataSource.invalidate();
```

After the invalidation, you won't be able to continue using the `DataSource`. However, the views from the adapter will not be detached automatically, so if you want to clear them, you should either provide from your `DataSource.Factory` a `DataSource` that will return no data either just clear the `RecyclerView.Adapter` manually.